# I have a column in a table that I would like to add up and display the result in a textbox. But its not working

Tags: php

I have a column in a table that I would like to add up and display the result in a textbox. But its not working.

```
<?php               
  function getpoint(){              
    $query = "SELECT sum(monthly_point) FROM characters WHERE 
               inmate_id = '$value'";                   

    $result_set = mysql_query($query);                  

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);              

    echo 'sum:'. $row[0];               
  }                 
?>
```

Comment: You are not connecting to a database within your function.Also (if you really want to keep using deprecated mysql functions) have a look at example 2 of PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Where the $value is coming from? It's not defined in the function, neither it is a function argument.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to mysqli instead of mysql functions (out of date and not as secure) and parameterized statements. Your code is susceptible to SQL injection.

Two problems in your code. Add an alias to the sum column, and reference the column in the echo statement:

```
<?php               
function getpoint() {
    $query = "SELECT sum(`monthly_point`) as `sum` FROM characters WHERE inmate_id = '$value'";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);      
    echo 'sum:'. $row[0]['sum'];
}               
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the field is correct? Are you connecting to a database?

Answer (score 0):

When you use var_dump() to display $row then it's OK ?

Please look it and add parameter as below
echo 'sum:'. $row['xxxxx'];

'xxxxx' : parameter